# Removing keywords from text to produce comma separated list

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have some text like this:

```
MAP land id|name, MAP region id|name|active, name, code,valid
COLLECTION:Group1
```

I am using this regular expression to remove certain words like as "MAP", "Collection" and also pipe separated words.

```
rEReplaceNoCase( data,"map|collection:|\s+|([[:alnum:]]+\|){1,}[[:alnum:]]*", ",", "ALL" )
```

The result *should* be a comma separated list of the remaining words. However, this is what the regular expression is producing:

```
,,,land,,,,,,region,,,,,,name,,code,valid,,Group1,
```

Is there a way to get rid of the unnecessary commas?

Comment: You're using `","` as the replacement text, change ...`",", "ALL" )` to `"", "ALL" )`

Comment: I guess you can use: `rEReplaceNoCase(data,",+", ",", "ALL" ) `

Comment: `is there any better way to get rid of unnecessary commas` Find `,+` Replace `,`

Comment: Please specify the desired result so that it's clear which commas are unnecessary.

Comment: Use a 2 step approach, you cannot use a conditional replacement pattern in Coldfusion regex.

Answer (score 0):

Coldfusion generally ignores empty elements in lists.  I suspect if you output listlen(yourresult), you'd get 6. So, as long as you're treating your result as a list -using list functions on it, looping over it using cfloop list, etc. - you don't really need to remove those empty elements.  If you're treating it as a string in coldfusion, outputting it, or passing it to another programming context, etc., then you'll probably want to remove the extra commas.  You can do this by converting it to an array and back again (as converting it is a list function, and therefore ignores empty elements):

```
<cfset temparray = listtoarray(yourresult)>
<cfset yourresult = arraytolist(temparray)>
```

Comment: That is a good observation. Though in this specific case, they should really fix the regex because as [@Mariano pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593618/removing-keywords-from-the-text-and-seprate-words-with-comma#comment64575509_38593618), replacing the unwanted words with `,` is what is causing all the extra commas in the first place :-)

Comment: @Leigh - it's a fair point! However, I think if you had two pipe separated entries next to each other in the original comma delimited list - eg. "my, list|looks, like|this, Leigh" you'd end up with extra commas anyway... (my,,,Leigh)? Using commas in the replacenocase is neither here nor there, if a solution that removes empty elements is required anyway.  I'm no regex guru, so I may be missing something. :)

Comment: Nothing against the notion of CF's default behavior of ignoring empty list elements. However, given that a bad expression is the *cause* of the problem, it just feels like a band-aid IMO *RE: end up with extra commas* Regex's are not my strength, but ... I am pretty sure suspect that could be handled with the correct expression. I would probably use multiple expressions, but a regex guru could almost certainly come up with something better ;-)